Filtering across multiple fields from a subquery where there is no related field
I'm trying to find a portable way to express the following record filtering query using the Django ORM.
The intention is to:

take a subquery of FilterSpec (eg. with a common FilterGroup)
find all instances of Record where Record.text1 = FilterSpec.r_text1 AND Record.text2 = FilterSpec.r_text2 for at least one of the instances of FilterSpec in the subquery.
include the matching FilterSpec.filter_name in the returned instances of Record.

Record will have high cardinality, >100,000, after filtering typically <1000.
The subquery of FilterSpec will have low cardinality, typically <10.
Here is a list of the models:
class RecordGroup(Model):
    name = CharField(unique=True)
    # further data fields

class Record(Model):
    text1 = CharField()
    text2 = CharField()
    group = ForeignKey(RecordGroup)
    # further data fields

class FilterGroup(Model):
    name = CharField(unique=True)

class FilterSpec(Model):
    r_text1 = CharField()
    r_text2 = CharField()
    filter_name = CharField()
    group = ForeignKey(FilterGroup)

The challenge is that there is no formal relation between the record fields and the filter fields. There will be lots of repeated values in Record.text1 and Record.text2.
I've found or developed examples where:

there is one field being compared
there are two fields being compared by concatenating the two fields into one (but I expect this will be slow at scale)
there is a Q expression enumerating the FilterSpec subquery

I haven't found a way where a field like FilterSpec.filter_name gets passed through.
However, this isn't particularly complicated in raw SQL:
SELECT record.text1, record.text2, record.further_data, filterspec.filter_name, recordgroup.further_data
FROM record
LEFT JOIN filterspec
    ON record.text1 = filterspec.r_text1
    AND record.text2 = filterspec.r_text2
LEFT JOIN filtergroup
    ON filterspec.group_id = filtergroup.id
LEFT JOIN recordgroup
    ON record.group_id = recordgroup.id
WHERE filtergroup.name = "example-filter-group-17";

Can anyone see an ORM-based solution, ideally avoiding raw SQL or even .extra() and other methods likely to be deprecated? For me it would need to work on SQLite (for dev) and with MySQL/MariaDB (prod) but ideally it should work on all SQL backends.

I don't think this is currently possible.  related question

Thanks @LordElrond, I found that answer in my research, but was hoping the situation may have changed in the decade since then.
